# Rules - event stopped triggering itself

Tags: commerce, rules

I have two questions, both related to rules

1) It seems, all of a sudden and no idea why, 'When an order is first paid in full' is not triggering anything. I have a custom payment method, which worked fine till today. I can confirm that commerce_payment_transaction_save works and updates the order with payment information and status changes to 1. So I don't know why 'paid in full' event stopped working. 
I am still able to trigger 'Completing the checkout process' event without problem.

2) Is there any module or perhaps an existing devel configuration that would allow to see rules log? Or debug by rules/events/actions?

Answer (score 0):

Rules has its own set of debugging options. Using Drupal 7? Try `/admin/config/workflow/rules/settings` and then check your recent log messages at `/admin/reports/dblog`. As a last resort, it might help to print some manual code just so you know that the rule is being triggered.

More info on debugging Rules: https://drupal.org/node/1593278